# IO error in Perl - can't find the input file.

Tags: perl, io

I'm very new to programming in perl, and I'm trying to just write a script to take a text input, assign it to a scalar variable, and print the input to the screen. My script keeps throwing an error of "No such file or directory at ~/Documents/Alignments/Ref/Test/Simple2.pl line 11". It seems like it's looking for the input within the script, not in the parent directory. I've tried multiple workarounds like just setting the filename to the text file like:

```
$filename = 'Try2.txt';
```

but it keeps giving me that same error. I'm sure I'm missing something exceedingly obvious, but it's eluding me.

Full script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;

#Define filename
$filename = '~/Documents/Alignments/Ref/Test/Try2.txt';

#open the file or exit
open (FILE, $filename) or die "Could not open FILE, $!";

#assign data to scalar variable $seqfile
$seqfile = <FILE>;

#close
close FILE;

#output data
print "Here is the sequence data \n\n";
print $seqfile;
exit;
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Use `$ENV{HOME}`, as `~` is shell specific.

```
$filename = '$ENV{HOME}/Documents/Alignments/Ref/Test/Try2.txt';
```